# Bash script sets nvidia meta mode to the variable name instead of the variable

Tags: bash, nvidia

I have this bash script which is supposed to set the video/meta mode to the variable that is determined my the first command line argument.

It is supposed to set it to the mode in the variable it's called with, instead it sets it to the variable name.

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
TV="DPY-0: nvidia-auto-select @1440x900 +0+0  {ViewPortIn=1440x900, ViewPortOut
TV_notear="DPY-0: nvidia-auto-select @1440x900 +0+0  {ViewPortIn=1440x900, View
NOTV="DPY-0: nvidia-auto-select @1440x900 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1440x900, ViewPortOu

echo "Setting display preset to $1"
nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="$1"
exit $?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for what you want is `${!name}`

```
echo "Setting display preset to ${!1}"
nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="${!1}"
```

Comment: Indeed. The name of the feature is [variable indirection](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Indirection).